# How does gas price / deployment cost scale with network size?

Tags: gas-price

Holding ether/usd price constant, how does the amount of gas for a transaction scale as more ethereum nodes are added? Does it become more expensive to execute the same transaction, since there are many more miners trying to do the same thing -- or is it constant, since only one can include it?

If it's the former, isn't that an extremely large barrier to entry? If I make a gambling dapp that only my community of 100 people would ever care about, would using it cost something on the scale of n=world_population (variable) rather than n=100 (fixed)?

Answer (score 1):

> Holding ether price constant, how does gas price scale as more
>   ethereum nodes are added?

if the ether price is constant, gas price will be the same when more transaction or mining nodes will be added

> Does it become more expensive to execute the same transaction, since there are many more miners trying to do the same thing -- or is it constant, since only one can include it?

it's the same price for the same ether price

> If it's the former, isn't that an extremely large barrier to entry? If
>   I make a gambling dapp that only my community of 100 people would ever
>   care about, would using it cost something on the scale of
>   n=world_population (variable) rather than n=100 (fixed)?

More people will use your dapp, more gas they will spend and it's a linear dependency. You can set-up a private ethereum network to run your contracts and make payout in the main network with some interledger dapp. Or you can set-up a hybrid network with trustfull validators but much cheaper gas price. I'm working on a project which will help to set-up that type of hybrid network. Please let me know if you'd like to know more.